# Pilates breathing and core engagement

Tags: breathing, core, pilates

I am new to pilates and have been working on my lateral breathing. It gets  tiring doing it alone. But when I do it with simple mat exercise like roll up, I sometimes feel like I am out of breath or like I don't exhale well. Lot of repetitions makes me feel heavy in the chest area.

1. Can anyone please suggest me a strategy to learn / master Pilates breathing ?
2. I am working on core engagement at exhale. How important is pelvic floor muscles for core engagement?
3. Once engaged,  do you release the pelvic floor, abs, ribcage engagement at the next inhale ? If not how to breathe/inhale well this engaged position?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pilates we use only diaphragmatic breathing. That is breathing with the help of ribs.
If you want to breathe correctly, you can put your arms on laterally ribs. 
When you do inhale, your ribs go to the sides. The chest doesn't rise, the shoulders are fixed and don't rise to the top too. In this moment your lungs get more oxygen.
When you exhale, try to keep the ribs to the center and down. 
If you will do it right, you can see your arms on ribs in inhale  to the sides (breathe through the nose) and back to the center in exhale (breathe through the mouth).